# CakePHP 3: Inflector class not found

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In one of my "Elements" I'd like to use the **`Inflector`** class, but it always shows

> **Fatal error: Inflector class not found.**

How do I include this class in cake way in my view files?

I tried to add **`use Cake\Utility`** and **`use Cake\Utility\Inflector`**, but neither of them helped.

Comment: Have you put the `use Cake\Utility\Inflector` in the element itself? If so, you should just be able to reference it as `Inflector::humanize` or whatever. Can you find and post a minimal complete piece of code that displays the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
\Cake\Utility\Inflector::humanize('Inflector working in the view')
```

fully qualified namespace from anywhere like Model, View or Controller

> **Note: Do no forget to use "\" at the start!**

Answer (score 1):

You can just fully qualify the inflector class methods i.e. `Cake\Utility\Inflector::method()` e.g.

```
<?= Cake\Utility\Inflector::humanize('Inflector working in the view') ?>
```

OR

You can just create a custom helper class, use the Inflector class there and then call the custom helper method in your view.

Comment: The fully qualified name solved the issue. One can also add `namespace Cake\Utilitý` in order not to repeat it every time.

Comment: How can I user Inflector in helper i got same error in helper?